# How can I access the header in the layout from the page NUXTJS?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

How can I access the header in the layout from the page?

Layout:

```
<template lang="pug">
  .glob
      h1.title {{ head.title}} // how i can?
      Nuxt

</template>
```

page:

```
head() {
    return {
      title: this.pageTitle,
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
computed: {
    headerData() {
      return this.$route.matched.map(r => {
        return r.components.default.options.data().title
      })[0]
    }
  }
```